# CakePHP 2.6 losing Auth settings when redirecting

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I'm having trouble with CakePHP losing my Auth settings when I'm redirecting from one controller action to another.

I set it here:

```
$this->Auth->login($this->Authuser);
if($this->Auth->user())
        {
            //debug($this->Auth->user());
            return $this->redirect(array('action'=>'parentportal',$guardianid));
        }
```

If I uncomment the debug it will show the data in $this->Auth->user.  But then when I go to the redirect...

```
    public function parentportal($guardianid){
      $userData=$this->Auth->user();
     }
```

If I debug here then there's nothing in the value.

I've had a good hunt around on the web and the answers I've found all seem to say to tweak the Security.level value in core.php - but this value isn't read in this version of Cake (as I understand it).  I even entered it in core.php to see if it might work and nothing changed.

Here's my controller definition:

```
class UsersController extends AppController {
    public $components = array('Auth','Session','Epd');

    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('logout','login','selectorg','consent','parentportal');
    }
```

Can anyone show me what I'm missing here?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS?

Comment: If you can, please consider posting the results of `debug(Configure::read('Session'));`

Comment: `$this->Auth->login($this->Authuser);` sounds to me like you are shooting yourself in the foot here. You should not have to use this method with actual params.

Comment: This is for a procedure which emails a user a 25 character token, and when they click on it in their email - needs to log them into the system without going through a u/p box.  That's why there's data being passed to $this->Auth->login.

Comment: debug(Configure::read('Session'));  gives the following output:

array(
 'cookieTimeout' => (int) 0,
 'checkAgent' => false,
 'cookie_secure' => false,
 'referer_check' => false,
 'defaults' => 'php'
)

Comment: Not redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS - all procedures are being done in HTTPS for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing params into `login()` which logs anyone in.

[Check the details on how to configure your login method in the book, and note the pink box](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#identifying-users-and-logging-them-in).

[image: Cakephp book notice]

So you should be using `$this->Auth->login()`

Comment: This is for a procedure which emails a user a 25 character token, and when they click on it in their email - needs to log them into the system without going through a u/p box. That's why there's data being passed to $this->Auth->login

Comment: Well you are allowing anyone to login to your application.

Comment: @Mortovski Just fetch the user data once they reach through the email link and write it to session data so that it will be available to you through `$this->Auth->user()`. see [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html#interacting-with-session-data). But allowing user to login via email link can lead to vulnerability in your application.